# db.collection.find() returning empty array in node.js but works properly in mongo shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So essentially I'm trying to find a specific document by querying the attribute "uid". I get the "uid" from the url and then based on that I want to render a different view and pass the document from the find() function but it's just returning an empty array. The "uid" is being grabbed correctly from the url as I confirmed with a console.log statement but when I console.log the doc that results from find() it's empty! So confused because when I run the command in the mongo shell it returns the correct document.

```
/*GET UserDetails page.*/ 
router.get('/userdetails', function(req, res) {
  var queryID = req.query.uid;
  //console.log(queryID);
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  collection.find({"uid" : queryID},{},function(e,docs){
      //console.log(docs);
      res.render('userdetails', {
          "userinfo" : docs
      });
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the working query look like?

Comment: It returns the document that has the same "uid"                                                         { "username" : userOne, "uid" : 1 }

Comment: Not the response, the query.

Comment: @Joe sorry I misread that, the query is {"uid" : 3}. I also checked that the value of queryID is 3. The entire command in mongo shell is db.usercollection.find({"uid" : 3},{})

Comment: What's the data type for the uid property?

Comment: @mustache i don't explicitly define it but it is an integer

Comment: @mustache smart person - the typeof queryID is a string and the type of "uid" attribute is integer! That's the issue solved

Answer (score -1):

I think db.get will return the promise so u need to await for db.get statement or u should use .then to capture the response.

Comment: i thought that as well so I switched function with async and put await in front of db.get but still no luck. Same empty array when I console.log